# IQueryable Where fails to work

Tags: c#, nhibernate, model-view-controller

I am using N-Hibernate and have a class/table called Boxers

I also have a prospect table which tells use if the boxer is a prospect. (this table is one column of just the boxersID)

So i Want to get all boxers that are prospects (meaning all boxers that have there id in the prospects table)

```
Public static IQueryable<Boxer> IsProspect(this IQueryable<Boxer> query)
{
return query.Where(x => x.Prospect != null);
}
```

this doesnt trim down my list of boxers to the boxers that are prospect... yet if i debug and look at any boxer it will have True or false next to each one correctly...

Why isnt the where clause correctly trimming down the list?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting rid of the prospects table and adding a column to the Boxers table called something like 'IsProspect' that is just a boolean of some sort. This will simplify your database schema and your NHibernate mappings.

Other than that, checking that `x.Prospect` is not null will return all `Boxer`s. Instead, use this line:

```
return query.Where(x => x.Prospect);
```

Just check that the boolean value is true, instead of checking that it's not null.

Comment: i would prefere not to put the prospect into the table as it isn't the same thing

your line of code (moving the "!= null") fails as cannot do a 
object of Prospect == bool

Comment: @Steve I think Aaron is assuming (and this is how I read it, too) that `x.Prospect` is a `bool` property of `Boxer`. This is also why your method returns all of the `Boxer` objects -- neither `true` nor `false` is `null`.

Comment: I guess I don't see why your code is the way it is. What exactly is the `Prospect` object? If it has nothing more than a reference to a `Boxer`, then it is extra unnecessary complexity as far as I can see. 

However, if the true/false you're seeing "next to each one correctly" is in the `Prospect`, then you should `return query.Where(x => x.Prospect != null && x.Prospect.IsProspect)`.

Comment: the prospect object is currently only a list of boxerid (but there will be more fields in it in future) 
there isnt any boolean on the prospect table.

Comment: If there is no boolean, then what do you mean by this? "yet if i debug and look at any boxer it will have True or false next to each one correctly"